# need explanation for this F# code from Expert F# chapter 15: working with data

Tags: sql, f#

this some code that i got from expert F# chapter 15.

```
let dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter()
let buildDataSet conn queryString =
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand <- new SqlCommand(queryString,conn)
    let dataSet = new DataSet()
    let _ = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter)
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet) |> ignore
    dataSet

let dataSet = 
    buildDataSet conn "SELECT * FROM Employees"
```

if i want to delete data or insert data should i make a new dataSet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind using `DataSet` for working with data is that the `DataSet` represents a local in-memory copy of some part of the database. To modify the database, you would modify the data stored in the `DataSet` (in memory) and then submit the changes to the database using the `SqlDataAdapter`.

The snippet you posted uses the `Fill` method to copy data from database to `DataSet`. Submitting changes from memory to database (the other direction) is done using the `Update` method.

You can find some C# examples in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). It shouldn't be difficult to translate them to F#.

If you don't need to keep data in memory, it may be easier to use `SqlCommand` directly. Using this type, you can create SQL command and immediately execute it on the SQL database (without copying any data to memory). You can find some examples in my [recent blog post](http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-sql.aspx). The blog shows how to read data using `ExecuteReader` method, but you can use `ExecuteNonQuery` method to just run command (without reading any results from the SQL server).